# How to create a crossword puzzle game in android

Tags: android

I'm gonna create a crossword game but I don't know how to make the table
I used table layout and it was not such a good idea because when I put a letter in one of the edit boxes all rows got move.

Anyone has a creative idea how to make it or did it before?Should I use game engines or like that?Please provide zoom and move capability in your ideas

P.S. The puzzle is 16x16

Comment: You could use gridview instead of table layout I guess or even better gridLayout if u are dveloping for newer devices.

Comment: try this https://github.com/abdularis/Word-Search-Game